# Concatenating in Excel based on Time

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have around `6000` sample values sorted incrementally based on time up to the minute e.g `1/11/2015 01:05` , `1/11/2015 01:06` and another excel sheet that has another kind of sample values but sorted incrementally based on time up to the hour e.g. `1/11/2015 01:00` , `1/11/2015 02:00` etc... Now I want to merge the second one with the first one assuming that the second sheet hourly sample values should be repeated for every minute on the first sheet, of course by respecting the hour unit. How should i do this?

[image: first sheet]

[image: second sheet]

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data? If I understand correctly, all the rows for the hour of `01:00` on sheet 1, you want to copy the data from sheet 2 where the hour is `01:00`?

Comment: @Jonno yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1))
```

Where `Sheet2!B:B` is the column of values you want to copy into your sheet, `A1` is the date and time to compare against, and `Sheet2!A:A` is the column of dates the compare with. The last argument, `1`, specifies it should be equal to or less than the lookup value.

[image]

[image]